# React-native simple image processing

Tags: react-native, image-processing

I'm working on a react-native app (called Killer Sudoku Helper FWIW) and would like to add a feature that uses the camera to load a puzzle (e.g. from a newspaper). It would need to scan a photo image and detect the location and thickness of the different lines that make up the puzzle.

I think I could do this if I have access to a bitmap image, however react-native-camera returns a JPEG image. I've looked at using Jimp (https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) to convert from JPEG to BMP but I've been unable to get it to work with react-native (per Jimp issue #761).

I'm wondering if/what alternative solutions are available?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question in case anyone's interested: I ended up using jpeg-js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js) instead of Jimp to convert from JPEG to Bitmap,  jpeg-js is a dependency of Jimp and is used by Jimp for this same purpose.